# Saved photos don't appear on device after update

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, filepath

On my iPhone app, I'm saving pictures associated with an event via this code:

```
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file

self.thisTransaction.picPath = filePath;
```

Later I retrieve and display the photo with this code:

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:thisTransaction.picPath];
```

Works great on my iPad (I don't have an iPhone).

However, if I update the app by connecting the iPad to my MB Pro after an Xcode code modification not involving the above lines, then disconnect and run it independently, the picture at the expected `picPath` is not retrieved. All other data associated with `thisTransaction` in Core Data is intact and unchanged, but the expected picture doesn't appear on the device after the update.

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

**Edit to clarify file path construction**

```
pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(capturedImage.scaledImage);

NSLog(@"1 The size of pngData should be %lu",(unsigned long)pngData.length);

//Save the image someplace, and add the path to this transaction's picPath attribute
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory



int timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

NSString *timeTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",timestamp];

filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:timeTag]; //Add the file name


NSLog(@"1 The picture was saved at %@",filePath);
```

The console log shows this filePath:

/Users/YoursTruly/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/65FB33E1-03A7-430D-894D-0C1893E03120/data/Containers/Data/Application/EB9B9523-003E-4613-8C34-4E91B3357F5A/Documents/1433624434

Comment: Show your code for the value of `filePath`. Most likely you are persisting the full path to the picture instead of the relative path. Never store an absolute path since that path can change over time. Only store the relative path and recalculate the absolute path at runtime, every time.

Comment: Please see edit above for filePath construction.

Comment: Your log output appears to be truncated. There should be a bunch more after `Applications`.  But again, you want to persist just the part after "Documents". Then each time you need to get the path for the Documents folder and append the part you should be saving.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last part. Please see modified edit above. Also, Could you please show an example and formalize in an answer. I'll be happy to check and up vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the location of an app's sandbox can change over time. Typically this happens when an app is updated. So the worst thing you can do is persist absolute file paths.

What you need to do is persist just the part of the path relative to the base path (the "Documents" folder in this case).

Then when you want to reload the file again, append the persisted relative path to the current value of the "Documents" folder.

So your code needs to be something like this:

**Save the file:**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
int timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *timeTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",timestamp];
filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:timeTag]; //Add the file name
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file

self.thisTransaction.picPath = timeTag; // not filePath
```

**Load the file:**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:thisTransaction.picPath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: Perfect, my friend! Works, and taught me a lot. Very grateful!